# Use ssh private key from untrusted computer

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, trust

I am currently working on a project from an *untrusted* computer and I would like to pull/commit changes from this (untrusted) computer using ssh authentication. I have access to my private (*trusted*) computer. Here is a summary of my setup:

- Git server with access *only with ssh* (no https authentication allowed)
- Trusted computer *with access* to the git server with ssh
- Untrusted computer *with no access* to the git sever but access to my trusted computer

What would you do in this case? (I can't copy files from the untrusted computer to the trusted computer. I want the files of this project to stay on the untrusted computer but I am allowed to send them to the trusted computer if I don't actually store them). They key idea is that I don't want other people using the untrusted computer to have access to my other projects on the git server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly try to get away using your trusted computer as an [SSH jump host](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+jump+host).

To cite [this manual](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host):

> An alternative to SSH tunneling to access internal machines
>   through gateway is using jump hosts.
>
> The idea is to use `ProxyCommand` to automatically execute ssh command
>   on remote host to jump to the next host and forward all traffic through.

This supposedly will require writing a wrapper script around the SSH client and setting the `GIT_SSH` env. variable to point to it—see
the "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" section in `git help git`:

> `GIT_SSH`, `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`
>
> If either of these environment variables is set then git fetch and git push
>   will use the specified command instead of ssh when they need to
>   connect to a remote system. The command will be given exactly two
>   or four arguments: the `username@host` (or just `host`) from the
>   URL and the shell command to execute on that remote system,
>   optionally preceded by `-p` (literally) and the port
>   from the URL when it specifies something other than the default SSH port.
>
> `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` takes precedence over `$GIT_SSH`,
>   and is interpreted by the shell, which allows additional
>   arguments to be included.  `$GIT_SSH` on the other hand must be
>   just the path to a program (which can be a wrapper shell
>   script, if additional arguments are needed).
>
> Usually it is easier to configure any desired options through your
>   personal `.ssh/config` file. Please consult your ssh documentation for
>   further details.

(I beleive the `SSH_COMMAND` is a fairly recently addition to Git.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found an other solution which is probably less secure than what you are saying but which do the work in my setting. I simply use a private key recognized by the git server but I protect it with a strong password in order to make it only accessible by me and no other user. Do you see any other threat than brute force attack in this case?

Comment: A keylogger could read your password.